# Div's spilling into left column, do not want it to stretch to fit the blank area

Tags: html, css

In the screen shot, you will see where there is a white space, it will stretch to fit (width: 100%) http://i29.tinypic.com/24v0gma.png

The light yellow and darker yellow css class here, called **article**:

```
.article {
    padding:10px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

The left col css class here:

```
.col-left {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
    height:100%;
    width:20%;
    xpadding:0 5px 0 0;
    xfont-size:.8em;
    font-family:arial;
}
```

You can view the live page here: http://herkimer.edu/admissions/view_news/

How do I get it so the yellow boxes do not spill over into the left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do:

```
.article {
  margin-left: 100px; /* example */
}

.col-left {
  width: 100px; /* same as margin-left above, might not work with percentage */
}
```

Comment: Tip: Check out the CSS Cookbook from O'Reilly, if there's one lying around right now, there might also be an online edition. I have used it a lot for stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

may be add clear: right; to .col-left?

--edited
You can pack all divs on the right in a new div called .col-right and make it floats right aswell as giving it a width property. Then add clear:right; to your .col-left style. That would have the effect that the right column won't continue under the left one. I tested it with Firebug and it worked.

Comment: and of cource add a right floating div around your right content

Comment: The .col-left element is only as tall as the content.  The divs are flowing around it because the height property has no affect.

Comment: but if the right content is in a seperate  right floating div (with some width) and the left column has clear: right property, then you don't need a height. I tested it with firebug and it worked.

Comment: Update your answer to reflect that assertion.

Answer (score 1):

Divs are block level elements by default so they try to expand horizontally but they do not expand vertically even with a height:100% defined.

> [image]
>
> The div.col-left is only as tall as
>   the content it contains.

I suggest you nest all of the article divs in one div.  That will constrain them the way you want.

Change:

```
<div class="content-body">
  <div class="col-left">
  </div>
  <h1>Admissions Announcements</h1>
  <p style="padding:5px 0;">Page 1 of 1 pages </p>
  <div class="article odd">
  </div>
  <div class="article even">
  </div>
  <div class="article odd">
  </div>
</div>
```

To:

```
<div class="content-body">
  <div class="col-left">
  </div>
  <h1>Admissions Announcements</h1>
  <p style="padding:5px 0;">Page 1 of 1 pages </p>
  <div>
      <div class="article odd">
      </div>
      <div class="article even">
      </div>
      <div class="article odd">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added them all within one div, and put a red border on it, and it still spills into the left part of the page: http://i27.tinypic.com/m8zns9.png

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could wrap the elements in the right column in a new div with a class of "col-right".  I tested this with your code and the following CSS:

```
.col-right 
{    
   float:left;    
}
```